# Get width directly after Button.AutoResize is set

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm adding buttons dynamically to a `Form` and am trying to lay the out side by side. I'm perfectly content with using the latest `Button.Right` as a starting point for the next button (with a margin left between of course), but the buttons have to adjust to fit the text.

So, what I'm doing is setting the `AutoResize` property to true and then storing the `Right` property, which however does not work because I guess the resizing doesn't happen until the button is drawn (I think). I tried `Invalidate()`, `Refresh()`, `Update()` and I think a couple more functions, and of course all together, but to no avail, I still get the old position and the next button starts beneath this one.

So **the question** is, after setting `AutoResize` to true on a `Forms` component, how do I force it to resize so I can grab the new `Width`/`Right` without waiting for the window to be redrawn?

Thanks in advance!

Note: If all else fails I'll do a rough approximation of the width of the buttons based on the string's length, so don't bother with something too fancy as a solution, it's not a requirement that it is perfect

Comment: Consider using `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... Well, it definitely solved the problem at hand, but I'm still curious if there's a way to get `AutoResize` to do it's magic before you exit the function so you can use the new values...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Control's [GetPreferredSize Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getpreferredsize(v=vs.110).aspx) to obtain the final auto-sized dimensions.  The Font property must either be explicitly set or the Control must be parented to a displayed control such that it can *inherit* the Font to use in the layout.  In the following example, the control's `Parent` property is set so that it inherits the parent control's `Font`.

```
private Random rnd = new Random(1000);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    const Int32 xDelta = 5; // the horizontal distance between the added Buttons
    Int32 y = button1.Location.Y + 5 + button1.Height;
    Int32 x = button1.Location.X;
    Point loc = new Point(x, y);
    this.SuspendLayout(); // this is Form that is the Parent container of the Buttons
    for (Int32 i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
        Button btn = new Button { Parent = this, AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
        btn.Text = new string('A', rnd.Next(1, 21));
        btn.Location = loc;
        Size sz = btn.GetPreferredSize(Size.Empty); // the size of btn based on Font and Text
        loc.Offset(sz.Width + xDelta, 0);
        }
    this.ResumeLayout(true);
    }
```