# How do you make AutoSize happen immediately?

Tags: c#, winforms

**The problem**

I'm dynamically adding Buttons to the WinForm. As I do so, I'm repositioning existing Buttons to prevent overlap. The `AutoSize` property is being used to automatically set `Width`.

For longer text (that pushes Buttons beyond their default `Width`), the below code doesn't work.

For example:

- `b.Width` is 75 before `AutoSize` is set
- `b.Width` is 75 after `AutoSize` is set
- When shifting other Buttons, it shifts them by `b.Width + buffer` = 83
- However after `addButton()`completes, the `AutoSize` kicks in and sets the width to 150, overlapping the next Button which is only 83 pixels away instead of 158.

[image: Here is a picture demonstrating the result]

`AutoSize` appears to change the size of the control too late for it to be of use. How can I make it happen immediately?

**Attempt 1 - Code**

```
public void addButton(string text)
{
    const int buffer = 8;

    //Construct new button
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = text;
    b.AutoSize = true;
    b.Location = new Point(0, 0);

    //Shift over all other buttons to prevent overlap
    //b.Width is incorrect below, because b.AutoSize hasn't taken effect
    for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
        if (Controls[i] is Button)
            Controls[i].Location = new Point(Controls[i].Location.X + b.Width + buffer, Controls[i].Location.Y);

    Controls.add(b);
}
```

**Attempt 2**

Searched Google and StackOverflow for the following:

- c# autosize immediately
- c# autosize fast
- c# autosize not working

**Attempt 3**

Asking here.

**Last Resort**

If nothing else works, a timer could be set to reposition Buttons on each tick. However this is *very sloppy design*, and doesn't aid in learning the intricacies of `AutoSize`. I'd like to avoid this workaround if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best option (I haven't found a better solution), but what I have done in the past is reposition all of my autosize buttons by putting an event handler on one of them and changing their Locations on Resize.

Comment: I answered this in [Get width directly after Button.AutoResize is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784751/get-width-directly-after-button-autoresize-is-set/45786796#45786796)

Comment: @TnTinMn If you have previously answered the same question, then you should vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray,I tried, but the system would not allow it since my answer was not upvoted.  But hey at least my link provided the source for selected answer here and one of the the comments provided  the source for another answer.  Who says this site does not reward plagiarism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get width directly after Button.AutoResize is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784751/get-width-directly-after-button-autoresize-is-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` mode are applied only when the control is parented to the another control or form.

So invoke first

```
Controls.Add(b);
```

Now the `b.Size` will the adjusted accordingly and can be used in the calculations.

Alternatively, instead of `Size` property you can use the [`GetPreferredSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getpreferredsize(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the correct size without actually applying `AutoSize` and use it inside the calculations:

```
var bSize = b.GetPreferredSize(Size.Empty);

//Shift over all other buttons to prevent overlap
//b.Width is incorrect below, because b.AutoSize hasn't taken effect
for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
    if (Controls[i] is Button)
        Controls[i].Location = new Point(Controls[i].Location.X + bSize.Width + buffer, Controls[i].Location.Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) control does this work for you.

Place one on your form and try adding buttons in the following manner:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.AutoSize = true;
b.Text = text;
flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(b, 0);
flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the Resize event of the last button added. This will allow you to accurately change the locations of all of the buttons because now all of the buttons have been AutoSized.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var button1 = NewButton(0);
        button1.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        var button2 = NewButton(1);
        button2.Location = new Point(button1.Right, 10);

        var button3 = NewButton(2);
        button3.Location = new Point(button2.Right, 10);

        button3.Resize += (s, e) =>
        {
            button2.Location = new Point(button1.Right, 10);
            button3.Location = new Point(button2.Right, 10);
        };

        Controls.Add(button1);
        Controls.Add(button2);
        Controls.Add(button3);
    }

    private Button NewButton(int index)
    {
        return new Button()
        {
            Text = "ButtonButtonButton" + index.ToString(),
            AutoSize = true
        };
    }
}
```